# mysql MATCH AGAINST weird characters query

Tags: mysql

I have a table where the field "company_name" has weird characters, like "à","ö","¬","©","¬","†", etc. I want to return all "company_name"s that contain these characters anywhere within the string. My current query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 
    MATCH (company_name) AGAINST ('"Ä","à","ö","¬","©","¬","†"' in natural language mode);
```

But I keep getting no data from the query. I know this can't be the case, as there are definitely examples of them I can find manually. To be clear, the query itself isn't throwing any errors, just not returning any data.

Answer (score 1):

The minimun  word length is 3 pr 4 .

you can change it see manial

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

or use regular expressiions

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 
    ompany_name REGEXP '[Äàö¬©¬†]+';
```

Comment: I believe when you use `REGEXP`, you don't need the `MATCH` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE company_name LIKE '%[^0-9a-zA-Z !"#$%&''()*+,\-./:;<=>?@\[\^_`{|}~\]\\]%' ESCAPE '\'
```

This will find any wacky stuff, including wide characters or 'euro-ASCII' or emoji.

Comment: ...Depending on collation